# How to create a text script generation tool that can read test data from an excel file and convert it into a TCSL (similar to a C) format?

Tags: python, data-structures, automated-tests, scripting-language

I want to create a test script generation (TCSL files) tool. It should be able to read test data from an excel file and convert it into a TCSL (similar to a C) format. Tool is expected to be developed in python.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so can you post [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Not yet! I am very much new to programming.

Comment: In which case, your problem is far too broad. StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).please review [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)?